# Powershell get disks information

Tags: powershell

I intend to run this script to collect information about disks. When I plug a USB device, it should display the name, letter, serial number. The problem is when a newly USB device is plugged, the script redisplay information of all the disks previously plugged, and not just the last one.

```
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier volumeChange

write-host (get-date -format s) " Beginning script..."
do {
        $newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
        $eventType = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType
        $eventTypeName = switch($eventType)
        {
            1 {"Configuration changed"}
            2 {"Device arrival"}
            3 {"Device removal"}
            4 {"docking"}
        }
        write-host (get-date -format s) " Event detected = " $eventTypeName

        $diskdrive = Get-WmiObject win32_diskdrive
        if ($eventType -eq 2) 
        {   foreach($drive in $diskdrive)
            {
              out-host -InputObject "`nDevice: $($drive.deviceid.substring(4))`n  Model: $($drive.model)"

              $partitions = Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=`"$($drive.DeviceID.replace('\','\\'))`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
              foreach($part in $partitions)
              {
                Out-Host -InputObject "  Partition: $($part.name)"
                $vols = Get-WmiObject -Query "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=`"$($part.DeviceID)`"} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
                foreach($vol in $vols)
                {
                  out-host -InputObject "  Volume: $($vol.name)"
                  $serial = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Volume | where { $_.Name -eq "$($vol.name)\" } | select SerialNumber
                  out-host -InputObject "  Serial Number: $($serial.serialnumber)"
                  Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source 'usb2.ps1' -EntryType Information -EventId '1' -Category 0 -Message "Date:$(get-date -format s)   Event detected:$eventTypeName   Serial:$($serial.serialnumber)   Name:$($drive.model)"
                }
              }
            }
         }
        if ($eventType -eq 3)
        {
             Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source 'usb2.ps1' -EntryType Information -EventId '1' -Category 0 -Message "Event detected: $eventTypeName   Serial:$($serial.serialnumber)   Name:$($drive.model)"
        }

      Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
    } while (1-eq1) #Loop until next event
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
```

Comment: can't check now but iirc `$newEvent.SourceEventArgs` has some detail about the specific disk in it.

Answer (score 0):

Because you call the command :

```
$diskdrive = Get-WmiObject win32_diskdrive
```

This command give you every disks.

And if the action is a "device arrival" you start a "for" to display informations about disk.

```
    if ($eventType -eq 2) 
    {   foreach($drive in $diskdrive)
        { ... }}
```

In this "for" you need to control if the disk is new or not. So you have to know which disk is plug before start your program.

Moreover you can control which type of disk is plug with the WMI command (not sure for win_32). There is an option which give you a number to know the type of the disk (X for hard drive, X for USB, etc).

Sorry for my poor english and good luck :)